# Unable to properly split a string using "\n" in golang

Tags: string, go, split

I am trying to split the output of `free` command into 3 lines. A general output of free is

`total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:       16309236    11129884      860300      534300     4319052     4306208
Swap:      20971516      234236    20737280`

But when I am using strings.Split() of `golang` the `Split` function is now behaving as expected. I tried debugging it but could not find anything.

Kindly help.

```
package main

import "os/exec"
import "github.com/golang/glog"
import "fmt"
import "strings"
import "errors"

func thisWorks() {
    str_out := "hello world \n How are you \nthis is good"
    lines := strings.Split(str_out, "\n")
    fmt.Printf("lines is  \n%s\n", lines)
}

func GetFreeOutput() error {

    var errMsg string
    bytes_out, err := exec.Command("free").Output()

    // This shows that the output has 10 (newline) in it.
    fmt.Println(bytes_out)

    if err != nil {
        errMsg = "Error geting output of free command"
        glog.Fatal(errMsg)
        return errors.New(errMsg)
    }

    str_out := string(bytes_out)
    fmt.Printf("str_out is  \n%s", str_out)

    // This is not splitting the lines, it is converting the whole output to a single line.
    fmt.Println("\nLines are ", strings.Split(str_out, "\n"))

    index_of_newline := strings.Index(str_out, "\n")

    // This gives the index of "\n" as 79 on my machine, which is correct.
    fmt.Printf("\nIndex is %d", index_of_newline)

    fmt.Println("\nLine using index are ", strings.Split(str_out, string(str_out[index_of_newline])))

    return nil
}

func main() {
    err := GetFreeOutput()
    fmt.Printf("Error is %s", err)
}
```

Comment: Downvoters please let me know what went wrong in writing the question so that it can be improved in further questions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Split is working as you expect. The issue is with how you print the lines.

The second argument to Println below is a slice.

```
 // This is not splitting the lines, it is converting the whole output to a single line.
fmt.Println("\nLines are ", strings.Split(str_out, "\n"))
```

Per the [fmt](https://godoc.org/fmt) documentation, a slice is printed as:

```
[elem0 elem1 ...]
```

Notice that elements are separated by spaces.  Splitting by \n and printing will in effect replace \n with ' '.  Try this code to confirm that split is working as expected:

```
for i, line := range strings.Split(str_out, "\n") {
   fmt.Println(i, line)
}
```